# How do i fix this "convert list to BST" problem?

Tags: python, class, recursion, binary-search-tree

why isn't my `Tree` object retaining the values i pass it?
It always keeps on printing `None` each time i run the script.

**class:**

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,key=None):
        self.left,self.right = None,None
        self.key = key

    def insert(key):
        return Tree(key)

    def convert(self,list):
        if len(list) > 1:
            mid = len(list)//2
            self = Tree.insert(list[mid]) 
            self.left = Tree.convert(self,list[:mid])
            self.right = Tree.convert(self,list[mid+1:])
        else:
            try:
                self = Tree.insert(list[0])
            except:
                self = None

        return self
```

**Input:**

```
int_list = [1,2,3]
```

**Main:**

```
tree = Tree()
tree.convert(int_list)

print(tree.key)
print(tree.left.key)
print(tree.right.key)
```

**Expected Output**

```
2
1
3
```

**Output Received**

```
None
```

can there be a way to fix this issue while keeping the `convert()` as a method of the class `Tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `convert` method doesn't do anything with the current value of `self`, but overwrites it. The main program calls the method on `tree` (which is `self` in the function), but as `self` is discarded and another value is assigned to this local name, the main's `tree` remains unaltered.

It is also apparent that you recursively call `convert` as a static method, directly on `Tree`. This is actually going in the right direction, but you should also do it in your main program, and then declare the `convert` method as a static method -- without a `self` parameter. The main program should use the tree node that this method **returns**.

Here is the version with minimal corrections, with comments indicating where changes were made:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        self.left,self.right = None,None
        self.key = key

    def insert(key):
        return Tree(key)

    # Define as static, without a self parameter
    @staticmethod
    def convert(list):
        if len(list) > 1:
            mid = len(list)//2  
            self = Tree.insert(list[mid]) 
            # As convert is now static, don't pass self argument
            self.left = Tree.convert(list[:mid])
            self.right = Tree.convert(list[mid+1:])
        else:
            try:
                self = Tree.insert(list[0])
            except:
                self = None

        return self

int_list = [1,2,3]

# Don't call the Tree constructor, 
# but get the root from calling `convert` as a static method
tree = Tree.convert(int_list)

print(tree.key)  # 2
print(tree.left.key)  # 1
print(tree.right.key)  # 3
```

This works, but still has some things that need to be improved:

- It is better practice to not use the name `self` when it is not an instance method (as is now the case here). You could name it `root`.
- Your code will be shorter (without that `try`) when you use as base case the case where the list *is empty* (instead of having 1 element).
- Don't use `list` as name -- it is already used for the native `list` type.
- The method `insert` is so basic that it doesn't really give any advantage. It is actually shorter code to call `Tree` than `Tree.insert`. So just drop that `insert` method.
- The `Tree` constructor should not have a default value for `key`. It is bad practice to create a root node that has no value. An empty tree has *no* nodes, not one. So remove that `=None` part.
- You can assign `None` to both `left` and `right` by chaining `=`.

So we get this:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, key):  # No default for key.
        self.left = self.right = None  # chain assignment
        self.key = key

    # No need for insert method

    # Define as static, without a self parameter
    @staticmethod
    def convert(values):  # Don't use list as name
        if values:
            mid = len(values)//2
            root = Tree(values[mid])  # Call constructor directly
            root.left = Tree.convert(values[:mid])  # No self argument
            root.right = Tree.convert(values[mid+1:])
            return root

int_list = [1,2,3]

# Don't call the Tree constructor, 
# but get the root from calling `convert` as a static method
tree = Tree.convert(int_list)

print(tree.key)  # 2
print(tree.left.key)  # 1
print(tree.right.key)  # 3
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot for your wonderful explanation and further elaboration. Thank you for providing some tips to improve my code and pointing out the mistakes I've made.

Comment: I just had one last question, could there be a way to create an instance method for the exact same purpose?

Comment: An instance method goes a bit against the general idea of the purpose here: you would need an instance first and then load the data, but you actually want to use the data to create instances (so it's a bit the opposite order of actions), and so you wouldn't start out with an instance. And then an instance method is not useful.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide any references/resources so that i could get an in depth knowledge for instance method for BST or in general, would really much appreciate it.

Comment: There are many good books on Python and Object Oriented Programming.